# How to show the limit of two functions in a code approach zero?

Tags: list-manipulation, calculus-and-analysis, performance-tuning, code-request, code-review

I don't know how to shorten the program, the entire code is required to understand everything:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
A = Rationals;
F[r_] := Range[-r*r!, r*r!]/(r!) (* The union of F_r from r=1
to Infinity is A*) 
F1[j_] := 
 DeleteDuplicates[Flatten[Table[Range[-t*t, t*t]/(t), {t, 1, j}]]]
(* The union of F1_j from j=1 to Infinity is A*)

epsilon = 2; (* epsilon is a constant integer *)

U[r_] := U[r] = Partition[F[r], UpTo[epsilon]] 
(* Partitions 'F[r]' into sublists with epsilon
elements *)
S[r_] := S[r] = 
  Table[U[r][[x, RandomInteger[{1,epsilon}]]], {x, 1, 
    Length[U[r]] - 1}] (* Take a point from each sub-list of 'U' *)
Pathway[r_] := Pathway[r] = Sort[S[r]]
(* Sorts S into path from least to greatest *)
    
Dist[r_] := 
 Dist[r] = 
  Table[EuclideanDistance[Pathway[r][[x]], Pathway[r][[x + 1]]], {x, 1, Length[Pathway[r]] - 1}] 
(* Takes distance between pairs of consecutive elements*)
PD[r_] := 
 PD[r] = N[Dist[r]/Total[Dist[r]]] (* Converts 'Dist[r]' 
 into probability distribution *)
    
EPD[r_] := 
 EPD[r] = -Total[
    PD[r] Log[2, PD[r]]] (* Take entropy of distribution *)

U1[j_] := 
 U1[j] = Partition[F1[j],UpTo[epsilon]] (* Partitions 'F1[j] into 
sublists with epsilon elements *)
S1[j_] := 
 S1[j] = Table[
   U1[j][[x, RandomInteger[{1,epsilon}]]], {x, 1, 
    Length[U1[j]] - 1}] (* Take a point from each sublist *)
Pathway1[j_] := 
 Pathway1[j] = 
  Sort[S1[j]] (* Sorts S into path from least to greatest *)
Dist1[j_] := 
 Table[EuclideanDistance[Pathway1[j][[x]], Pathway1[j][[x + 1]]], {x, 
   1, Length[Pathway1[j]] - 1}]
(*Takes distance between pairs of consecutive elements*)
PD1[j_] := PD1[j] = N[Dist1[j]/Total[Dist1[j]]]
(*Converts 'Dist1[r]' into a probability distribution*)
EPD1[j_] := 
 EPD1[j] = -Total[
    PD1[j] Log[2, PD1[j]]] (*Take entropy of distribution*)

j1 = 80; (* We want j1 to be large as possible, such the code is \
efficient *)
TED1 = Table[EPD1[j], {j, 2, j1}] ;(*Takes list of EPD1[j]*)
LowS[r_] := 
 LowS[r] = 
  Length[S1[
    Flatten[Position[TED1, Max[Select[TED1, # <= EPD[r] &]]]][[1]]-1]]
(* 'UpS' is Length of S1 for j-integer such EPD1[j] is the greatest \
of EPD1[j]<=EPD[r] *)
UpS[r_] := 
 UpS[r] = Length[
   S1[Flatten[Position[TED1, Min[Select[TED1, # >= EPD[r] &]]]][[1]]-1]]
(* 'LowS' is Length of S1 for j-integer such EPD1[j] is the smallest \
of EPD1[j]>=EPD[r] *)

lowa[r_] := 
 lowa[r] = 
  N[Length[S[r]]/LowS[r]] (* I want 'lowa' for large r such
as r->Infinity 'lowa' approach zero *)
topa[r_] := 
 topa[r] = 
  N[Length[S[r]]/UpS[r]] 
(* I want 'topa' for large r such as r->Infinity 'topa'
approach zero*)
```

I want to show as `r`→∞, for integer `r`, the part `lowa[r]` and `topa[r]` (at the bottom of the code) approach zero. I only could compute `lowa[r]` and `topa[r]` up to `r=7`. I also need `j1` to be as large as possible to get outputs for larger `r`.

**Question:** How do we compute `lowa[r]` and `topa[r]` for a large `r` and `j1` such that `lowa[r]` and `topa[r]` is close to zero.

Comment: Executing   `TED1 = Table[EPD1[j], {j, 2, j1}]`. I obtain "Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0 encountered." and a lot of zeros.

Comment: @user64494 My computer doesn’t show any errors (e.g. when `j1` is 80 and `r` is 7).

Comment: You are right. Having executed it on a fresh kernel , I obtained `{1.45915, 3.12893, 4.04409, 5.03906,..., 16.2173, 16.2545}`. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: Something to adjust: `topa[x]` results in "Range::range: Range specification in Range[-x x!,x x!] does not have appropriate bounds." and "Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0 encountered." and `1.`. As far as I understand it, `topa[x]` cannot be expressed symbolically  so only  `NLimit` may be applied.

Comment: `topa[7.9]` produces several errors (for example, "Table::iterb: Iterator {t,1,{}[[1]]} does not have appropriate bounds.") and `257298.`.

Comment: @user64494 `r` should be an integer. I also made edits, there were some flaws.